# Using puppet module straight from a cloned repo

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I'm trying to use puppet module in a vagrant setup. In a worked around the problem I tried to solve in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508081/installing-a-puppet-module-from-a-manifest-script).
I cloned the puppet module repo (apt module and nodejs module) into a sub folder
set the puppet module path in the vagrantfile

And include the puppet modules and call them in the puppet manifest file for example:

```
class { 'apt':
}
include apt

class{ 'apt':} -> apt::builddep { ["python-imaging","python-lxml"]:
    require => Class['apt'] 
 }
```

I wonder, maybe there is an install/build step I'm missing when I just `git clone` the repo? is this even possible to do?

The error message:

```
←[0;37mdebug: importing '/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/apt/manifests/init.pp' in
 environment production←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: Automatically imported apt from apt into production←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: importing '/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/apt/manifests/params.pp'
in environment production←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: Automatically imported apt::params from apt/params into production
←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: importing '/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/apt/manifests/update.pp'
in environment production←[0m
←[0;37mdebug: Automatically imported apt::update from apt/update into production
←[0m
Unknown function validate_bool at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/apt/manifests/in
it.pp:36 on node precise32
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

cd /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests && puppet apply --verbose --debug --modulepath
'/etc/puppet/modules:/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0' default.pp --detailed-exitco
des || [ $? -eq 2 ]
```

Comment: I had a problem very similar to this, one thing I noticed was that the cloned repo was named `puppetlabs-nodejs` but I had to rename it to `nodejs` otherwise my puppet apply would not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `stdlib` module, which is a dependency at least of the `apt` module, and which provides, among other things, the `validate_bool` function Puppet can't find.

You can find the `stdlib` module here:
https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib

Use the Puppet module installation tool rather than just cloning a single repo.

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_installing.html

or better yet use librarian-puppet.